# Accessing variable from callback using AJAX in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code explains all:

```
//
// … code ...
//
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "foo",
    success: function(data) {
        var my_data = data;
    }
});
//
// … code ...
//
console.log(my_data); // NOT in scope
```

How do I get access to `my_data` outside of the AJAX call?  I've read that maybe a closure is needed?  I can't find any examples that do want I want though.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't. AJAX calls are asynchronous so there's no guarantee of a value immediately after the `jQuery.ajax()` function has executed; you need to wait until the AJAX call has completed, and the `success` callback has executed, before you attempt to use that variable.

The easiest approach is to just use that value *inside* the `success` callback. If you really need it to be available outside then make it a variable that's visible to all of your code (not necessarily global, depending on how your code is structured), and check that it has a value before you attempt to use it in any other functions.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is `async` call and success may be fired after console.log, you can call a function from success and pass data to it.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "foo",
    success: function(data) {
        yourFun(data);
    }
});

function yourFun(data)
{
}
```

To giving function instead of success.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "foo",
    success: yourFun
});

function yourFun(data)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes it could be but for clarity of code we can define a function and call it.

Comment: Thumbs up :) In this particular case it looks clearer to me. But that's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Define `my_data` as global as below,

```
var my_data;

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "foo",
    success: function(data) {
        my_data = data;
    }
});
//
// … code ...
//
console.log(my_data); // NOT in scope
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare my_data variable globally..

```
var my_data = data;

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "foo",
        success: function(data) {
            my_data = data;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `my_data` as `gloabl` variable to access data outside of ajax.

```
var my_data = '';
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "foo",
    success: function(data) {
        my_data = data;
    }
});

console.log(my_data);
```